# Allow Googlebot to crawl dynamically generated product pages

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, google-search, googlebot

I have been doing some reading into how Googlebot crawls javascript generated webpages but am still a little confused on it.

Say I have a web page for company XYZ Inc that has 5 general products like bath towels and Pencils.

How do I allow Googlebot to index www.xyzinc.com/products/bath-towels so that it shows up in the google search results such as:

```
XYZ Inc. - Bath Towels
www.xyzinc.com/products/bath-towels
some description here
```

My one idea was to created a Site Map that has a generated list of all the products on the page in nested links with links that I can feed to the Google Search Console, but I do not know if that is the right way to go about doing it.

Comment: SEO questions belong on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before with dynamic pages. What helped me is:

- Add all those links to sitemap.
- Make links accessible via custom url. (let's say each search on my site will generate new page if it doesn't exist with its unique url).
- Make each page unique.

Answer (score 1):

I use 2 things to Allow Googlebot to crawl dynamically generated page

1. routing (create a smart URL)
2. I create statics Pages recaping my dynamicals pages with links to
   them